# Quiz, background condition doesnt work, using bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I have quiz app. If user click on answer, I am trying to add green background, if user selected correct answer. Green background is working, but if user selected wrong answer ,I want to add red background , and here is problem , some reason , red background doesn't work , can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
{question?.answers.map((item, i) => (
    <button
     className={`btn border w-100 mt-1 ${
      selectedAnswer === 'correct' && item.correct     // condition start here
      ? 'bg-success text-light'                        // green is working
      : selectedAnswer === 'wrong' && !item.correct     //  <<< problem
       ? 'bg-danger text-light'
          : ''   }`}
         key={i}
          disabled={disabledBtn}
                               
          onClick={() => {
              // {} can add more click events
            checkCorrectAnswer(item.correct)
             }}  >
                {item.text}
            </button>
     ))}
```

```
  const checkCorrectAnswer = (selected) => {

    setShowNextBtn(true);
    if (selected) {
      if (selected === true) {
         //    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   checking answer and add color
        setSelectedAnswer(selected === true ? 'correct' : 'wrong');
        setScore((prev) => prev + 1);
      }
    }
    setDisabledBtn(true);
  };
```

Comment: JavaScript is "falsey" in nature so where you have `(selected === true)` selected has a value sent as `item.correct` so it is always true so `!!selected == true` as is `!!selected` by itself

Comment: your `setSelectedAnswer(selected === true ? 'correct' : 'wrong');` can go before that first `if(selected)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation for the method `checkCorrectAnswer()` looks a little buggy and complicated. Can try following following -

```
const checkCorrectAnswer = (selected) => {
  setShowNextBtn(true);
  if (selected) {
    setSelectedAnswer('correct');
    setScore((prev) => prev + 1);
  } else {
    setSelectedAnswer('wrong');
  }
  setDisabledBtn(true);
};
```

Comment: yes I see it now , there was too much if statements if correct answer is correct.

Comment: Is the provided solution worked?

Comment: yes , I want to accept it but must wait 3 min